# Left Nav only appearing for site collection admins

Tags: permissions, navigation

My group is working on a SharePoint 2010 upgrade and one of the critical defects weve seen is that the left navigation is only viewable to site collection admins.

Ive checked all the regular places for the left nav and nothing seems indicative of setting permissions for the left navigation.

Obviously im missing something here. Does anyone have any advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was there a custom masterpage in the old environment? Have you applied the visual upgrade? What have you checked in the master page. My guess is that there may be some security trimming happening in that zone.

Comment: We did have a custom master page which we redid for 2010, and in our post deployment script we have a section for performing the visual upgrade, and right after going through all site collections and setting the new masterpage.

Comment: I am assuming you took care of it in your script, but just want to make sure the master page is indeed checked in and approved. I had something similar happen and thought my masterpage had been checked in successfully and approved, but in the end it hadnt.

Comment: It wasnt the masterpage, it was the page layouts. I guess our script only checks in the master page and not the newer page layouts. Thanks! I owe you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get the solution on this? I am having the same issue and struggling to find one. We have used LifeInSharepoint solution from code plex and used some javascript function to display left nav in webpart pages. But it is only visible for site collection admins.

Can any one help?

Comment: left nav doesnt show up in webpart pages, you need to do the following: http://secretsofsharepoint.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2012/08/02/display-the-left-navigation-menu-in-sharepoint.aspx

Comment: This would make a better comment than an answer. Please make comments comments and answers answers in the future, this can affect the question openers acceptance score.